# Benchmarking Disk Performance (Windows and Linux on Xen)

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, xen, paravirtualization

I am kind of new to the world of virtualization...I am doing some tests using different tools (iometer, fio, dd tool, and bonnie++). The idea is to benchmark the disk performance for different operating systems in a virtualized environment and for different types of virtualization (Paravirt. and Full-virt.).

The results out of those tests for Windows (XP, 7 and 8) were not as I expected with almost all tools, since I got a relatively high performance results without installing the paravirt. drivers for Windows, and what was more surprisingly that after installing the paravirt. drivers the performance decreased.

Samples of my tests using fio tool:

Writing a sequential file the with size of 16 GB and with block size of 512 KB

Windows 7 (Full-Virt.): 87.2 MB/s average aggregate bandwidth

Ubuntu (Paravirt.): 72.9 MB/s average aggregate bandwidth

Any ideas about what is going on here (I am using openSUSE as an OS in case it matters) !!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd downvote this if I could. Your core issue is you need to accurately identify the IO profile of the applications you are actually running. Writing 16 GB of sequential data is a very atypical workload.

Once you have a realistic understanding of the IO workload, you can then configure the testing tools to match.

Comment: But I am not targeting a specific application, and the reason why I am writing with such a file size is to avoid interfering with my cash memory.